# R regex between two strings or end of string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have strings like this one:

```
a = "USER  2020-02-09 01:13SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE.USER  2020-02-10 08:30and something else comes here"
```

I want to extract everything between the HH:MM time and the keyword "USER".

If I use a regex to locate what's between the time specification and USER with `sringr::str_extract_all`, I get:

```
str_extract_all(a, pattern = '([0-9]{2,}:[0-9]{2,})(.*)(?=USER)')

# [[1]]
# [1] "01:13SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE."
```

What can I add to the regex to say that it should search between HH:MM and USER **OR between HH:MM and the end of the string** (so that I'd also get `08:30and something else comes here`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use regex lookaround to do this

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(a, "(?<=\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*(?=USER)")
#[1] "SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE."
```

If we want to extract all the components

```
str_extract_all(a, "(?<=\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*(?=USER)|(?<=\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2})[^0-9]+$")
#[[1]]
#[1] "SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE."   "and something else comes here"
```

Or in a more compact way

```
str_extract_all(a, "(?<=\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2})[^0-9]+(?=(USER)|$)")
#[[1]]
#[1] "SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE."   "and something else comes here"
```

If the time component is also needed

```
str_extract_all(a, "\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2}[^0-9]+(?=(USER)|$)")
#[[1]]
#[1] "01:13SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE."   "08:30and something else comes here"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. Especially the `str_extract_all(a, "(?<=\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2})[^0-9]+(?=(USER)|$)")` is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a lookaround, you could use a match for either USER or assert the end of the string `(?:\bUSER|$)` and a capturing group `(.*?)`

```
[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9](.*?)(?:\bUSER|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EuW5U6/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/wgks21)

For example

library(stringr)

```
a = "USER  2020-02-09 01:13SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE.USER  2020-02-10 08:30and something else comes here"
str_match_all(a, "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9](.*?)(?:\\bUSER|$)")[[1]][, 2]
```

Output

```
[1] "SOMETHING INTERESTING HERE."   "and something else comes here"
```